# WebApi 2.1 + Backbone.js 1.1.2: sync everything at once

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api, marionette

*Disclaimer: I'm a WebApi/BackBone beginner, so the question might be a bit odd since there is a lot about these components I don't really know and/or understand.*

It would be nice to have the possibility to issue just ONE sync() call to the server to synchronize everything. I mean, when I saw sync() method, at first I thought it's used like that, but as soon as I saw the "create", "update", "delete" params I realized it's not. But there is an underlying problem related to Backbones default implementation for DELETE.

I've learned that classic implementation of Backbone.js allows one deleted (destroyed) model at a time to be sync'ed to the server. Created/modified (POST/PUT operations) content is sent in the request body itself, so the JSON is filled with the data and deserialized by WebApi model binding on the server. It doesn't work like that for DELETE, since body is always empty and reference to the model is made by URL parameters in query string. So, I guess to achieve that functionality, the request for DELETE should be sent in body as well as for POST/PUT.

**Is there a possibility to change all of this behavior AND make it work with WebApi?** I googled for that stuff already, but can't find anything to point me to the right direction.

What I have until now is a Backbone model, collection and a view set up.
`Backbone.sync("create", this.collection);` is called by the view on button click.
On the server side there is a WebApi controller set up with scaffolded methods:

```
// GET
public IEnumerable<Ponuda> Get()
{
    return _storageService.GetPonude().ToList();
}

// GET
public Ponuda Get(int id)
{
    return (Ponuda)_storageService.GetPonuda(id);
}

// POST
public void Post([FromBody]IEnumerable<Ponuda> value)
{
    _storageService.CreatePonude(value);
}

// PUT
public void Put([FromBody]IEnumerable<Ponuda> value)
{
    _storageService.ModifyPonude(value);
}

// DELETE
public void Delete(IEnumerable<int> value)
{
    _storageService.RemovePonude(value);
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm reading about Marionette.js and it seems to offer standard model/view related functionalities out of the box. However, I still can't see the possibility to save/sync e.g. the entire modified collection at once.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to do something like collection.delete([list of ids]) that would remove the models from the collection and send a DELETE request to the server with the ids in the body?

Comment: You need to rewrite a lot of code in backbone's source to achieve syncing of entire changes add/update/delete at once and I guess it will be not a REST-full way which backbone provides.

Answer (score 1):

To sync all contents at once :

- For `POST` and `PUT` Http methods, you can use Backbone.Sync API.
- For `DELETE`, you can directly use the `ajax` API for deleting the content in the server and use Backbone Collection [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) API to delete the content in the client side.

I have written skeleton code which demonstrates on how to achieve the functionality:

```
var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/demo',
    defaults: {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "",
        "age": 0
    }
});

var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/demo',
    model: PersonModel    
});

var model1 = new PersonModel({"name": "John", "age": 30});
var model2 = new PersonModel({"name": "Joseph", "age": 30});

var collection = new PersonCollection();
// model will be added locally on client side. It will not sync to the server.
collection.add(model1); 
collection.add(model2);

// POST. This will create both the models together using a single REST API request.
Backbone.sync('create', collection);
// PUT. This will update both the models together using a single REST API request. 
Backbone.sync('update', collection); 

// Extract the model ids to be deleted
var modelIds = [model1.get('id'), model2.get('id')]; 
$.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/demo',
    data: JSON.stringify(modelIds), // This will add ids to the request body
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function() { 
        // On successful deletion on server end, delete the models locally.
        collection.remove([model1, model2]); 
    }
});
```

Regarding the `WebApi`, since I have not worked on it, will not be able to guide you. Having worked on `Spring Rest` API, I can tell you above functionality should work with the WebApi.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question. Code using this approach wouldn't be dry, meaning there would be a lot of repeated code. Another thing is manual detection of deleted objects - why would I do that if Backbone already takes care of it? Or does it?